# SFMC SQL Query not ordering decimal values correctly

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I'm trying to order a record so that the latest date, and the highest value populate first and then decrease in a descending order.

This is what I've written:

```
SELECT contact__c,
       Ind_Assets_Retail__c,
       lastmodifieddate,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY contact__c
                         ORDER BY lastmodifieddate, ind_assets_retail__c DESC) as row_num
FROM contact_financial__c
```

I  tried isolating for just the date (lastmodifieddate) it was able to properly order the dates in descending order, but when I isolate the Order by clause to just the second field (ind_assets_retail__c) it doesn't order them logically.

The ind_assets_retail__c field is a decimal value. I've also tried to cast it as decimal in the query and it still did not return the results I wanted.

This is the result I get when I run the query:

| contact__c | Ind_Assets_Retail__c | lastmodifieddate | row_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 003U000001UODhiIAH | 0.00 | Jun 19 2021 6:52AM | 1 |
| 003U000001UODhiIAH | 0.00 | Jun 19 2021 6:52AM | 2 |
| 003U000001UODhiIAH | 38641.91 | Jun 19 2021 6:52AM | 3 |
| 003U000001UODhiIAH | 38641.91 | Jun 19 2021 6:52AM | 4 |

This is the result I actually want

| contact__c | Ind_Assets_Retail__c | lastmodifieddate | row_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 003U000001UODhiIAH | 38641.91 | Jun 19 2021 6:52AM | 1 |
| 003U000001UODhiIAH | 38641.91 | Jun 19 2021 6:52AM | 2 |
| 003U000001UODhiIAH | 0.00 | Jun 19 2021 6:52AM | 3 |
| 003U000001UODhiIAH | 0.00 | Jun 19 2021 6:52AM | 4 |

Comment: is this a text field or a decimal field?

Comment: it's a decimal field

Answer (score 2):

It's likely a data type issue as [@EasyE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/66853/eazye) suggested.  You should probably force the ordering by doing a cast/convert on the order-by columns.

Plus your output isn't showing the full precision on the `lastmodifieddate` -- there could be differences in seconds.

```sql
SELECT 
  contact__c
, Ind_Assets_Retail__c
, lastmodifieddate
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
       PARTITION BY contact__c 
       ORDER BY 
              convert(date, lastmodifieddate)
              , convert(decimal(18,2), ind_assets_retail__c) DESC
  ) as row_num
FROM contact_financial__c
```

Converting to `date` sets the time part of the date to midnight and converting the number to a decimal with precision will make it sort properly.